# Label for hidden date input not working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a date input and I want it to have a placeholder, so I added a label and a display none.
I have this code:

```js
    document.querySelector("#date").onchange = (e) => {
      document.querySelector("#datelabel").innerHTML = e.target.value;
    }
```

```css
    #datelabel {
        padding: 16px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
        outline: none;
        font-size: 20px;
        transition: .2s;
        width: 200px;
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
    <input type="date" name="date" id="date" style="display:none;">
    <label class="input" for="date" style="color:var(--text);" id="datelabel">Date</label>
```

It works fine on Firefox, but not on Chrome.
If I remove the display of none of the input, it works, but I don't want the real input to be visible.

I tried to set a height and width to `0`, an `overflow: hidden`, to remove the paddings and margins, but it created a mess in the display of my page, so I want to keep the display of none and find another solution.

Edit:
I hid it another way:

```css
position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;
```

It works now.

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to remove `display: none`, but on the bright side, hiding it using other methods should be relatively simple. If you include what you attempted perhaps we can help fix the "mess in the display of my page" that it caused.

Comment: I added position: absolute;visibility:hidden; and it works! Thanks!

Comment: Im a bit surprised that it works on FF. display: none I thought just doesn’t render the element at all. BTW the date picker doesn’t show when running on Safari (iOS) as well as not showing on Chrome. You could try giving input opacity 0 so it is still rendered but position absolute so it doesn’t mess up anything else layout wise, tucking it beneath its label perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works

```css
input {
    padding: 16px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    outline: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: .2s;
    width: 200px;
    display: block;
}
::placeholder {
  color:black;
  font-size: 25px;
  
}
```

```html
   <input type="text" name="date" id="date" id="datelabel" style="display:block;" placeholder="Date">
```

Comment: I can't set a placeholder to a date input, that's why I made it like this

Comment: check i correct the  my code

Comment: Ok but I want a date selector to appear when I click on the input, so it can't be a text input. By the way, I added an absolute position and visibility: hidden and it works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).